# How to save this biFir data to sql database using c#?

Tags: c#, sql, binary

I am using  `NITGEN.SDK.NBioBSP` module to capture finger print and here biFir holds the data.

I want to save to sql database. I need help!!!

`NBioAPI.Type.FIR biFIR;`

---

`m_NBioAPI.GetFIRFromHandle(hNewFIR, out biFIR);`

Comment: What part of saving data to sql you need help? Data Type? Connecting to DB? Creating a Model?

Comment: how can i save it to database converting it into image or directly biFIR? i don't even know what kind of data it holds. All i want is when i extract data from biFIR data that had been saved to database i should show image from it to picture box..

Answer (score -1):

Create: `Byte[] fingerBi;`
Next: `fingerBi = biFIR.Data;`

Now save to sql fingerBi

XD